# Magento 2 Varnish cache compilation failed

Tags: magento2, varnish

I configuring the Varnish cache in Magento 2.3(CE), for that I've gone through the below link.

https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/magento2-install-and-configure-varnish-cache-with-https-in-ubuntu-641

So based on this, I have done everything in my localhost. Moreover, I am not using any HTTPS & SSL.

Now my localhost URL as follows: http://127.0.0.1:8080.

Then using the following commands, I am checking the Varnish status

```
sudo service varnish restart - working fine
sudo service varnish status - Error: VCL Compilation failed
```

For your further reference herewith I've attached the error screen.

[image]

Currently Installed Varnish Version

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is what Varnish version you have installed, version 4 is very old and discontinued. magento default.vcl config is also outdated

as you can see from error message saying that `fetch` is deprecated. you can verify it from varnish docs:
https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-built-in-subs.html#vcl-hit

> **vcl_hit** Called when a cache lookup is successful. 
>   The vcl_hit subroutine may terminate with calling return() with one of
>   the following keywords:

```
fail synth restart pass deliver
```

your best option is to install *Varnish* **6** , latest version with long support.

Comment: I installed the varnish 6, but still, I am getting the same problem, I checked the currently installed version using  varnishd -V (the screen I've attached in question)

Comment: if you have varnish 6 and generated vcl file version 6, then it works ok. what error you have?

Comment: Thanks, after generated varnish six it's working perfect, previously I used the varnish four generated file